# How to create form slider with 5 values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create form slider like the screenshot.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJebP.png]

Comment: I searched in google and found that form slider are either numeric range type but not like the screenshot, which should have option of selecting, one of the five values. 
Please help.  

http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery selecttoUIslider component. This component takes the select form elements and  generates a jquery UI Slider element.

Here is an example from page.

**Markup**

```
 <select name="optiontype" id="idselect">
      <option value="Economy">Economy</option>
      <option value="Value">Value</option>
      <option value="Average" selected="selected">Average</option>
      <option value="Splurge a little">Splurge a little</option>
      <option value="Luxury">Luxury</option>
  </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#idselect').selectToUISlider();
```

You can check the demo page [here](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index2.html)

and Download the code from [here](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/FilamentGroup_selectToUISlider.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can try HTML5 input tag tyape=range like this

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range

```
<input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
```

you can also modify box using some css , :)

Comment: Note this isn't supported before Firefox 23 and IE10: http://caniuse.com/input-range

Comment: This is now (2021) well supported across browsers.